# What does the "is" attribute in Polymer mean?

Tags: polymer

What does the "is" attribute in Polymer stand for? I Googled about it but to no avail. From what I understand it is the identifier of the component, however I am not sure how it is related to "is". Is it an abbreviation of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is` attribute is not Polymer-specific but part of the web components spec, specifically the Custom Element part of the spec. It's how you extend native elements.

Source: http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#instantiating-custom-elements

Answer (score 0):

The `is`-Attribute is used to extend native HTML elements:

```
MyInput = Polymer({
  is: 'my-input',
  extends: 'input',
  ...
});
```

and later on

```
<input is="my-input">
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#type-extension).